# coIlection is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

collection is not defined... how to define?

I searched in https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection but found nothing

`collection.find(message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.displayName === args[0]));`

Comment: `message.guild.members.cache` *is* the collection. It's just like `Array.prototype.push()`. You don't literally `push()` the `Array.prototype` object, you make your *own* array, and `push()` *that*

Comment: You should specify that this is the browser console that is giving you the error, and should provide much greater context. Because collection is undefined it's likely an error regards loading and initializing the librar, you should post the js or html(cdn) that handles loading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Array.find():

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

The "collection" should be your own definition of an array of items.  In the mozilla reference array1 is the list of numbers and find is invoked on array1 - returning only the first item satisfying the condition.

It seems like you don't actually have a variable called collection in your code.  Perhaps you can try:

```
message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.displayName === args[0]);
```